# Can I cash a personal check against my business account?

Tags: united-states, check, washington

Can I cash a check made payable to me personally through my business checking account?  I'm a sole proprietor in Washington state (U.S.).

Comment: Are you actually cashing the check or depositing it into your business account?

Comment: I'm cashing it.  Made payable to me and has nothing to do with the business.  The bank is stating I have to endorse with pay to the order of my business name.

Comment: It's entirely up to the bank. Generally, they don't want to give you cash for a check that might bounce unless they have a way to retrieve the money, i.e., taking it out of your account. It sounds like they are essentially having you sign the check over to your business account, so that if the check bounces, they can recover the money from that account instead of having to go after you personally.

Comment: Is the bank asking you to do this because you don't have a personal account with the bank, only a business account? If yes, do you have a personal account at another bank, or can you go to the check's originating bank to cash it?